# Object creation

Tags: list, object, input, python-3.x

This is simply for the "Joy of Learning." I'm entirely self-taught from books and tutorials and still very new to programming. I'm trying to explore a concept of creating objects from a list. Here is what I have:

```
class Obj:   # Creates my objects
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.name = x
        print('You have created a new object:', self.name)

objList = []
choice = 'y'

while choice != 'n':   # Loop that runs until user chooses, 'n' to quit
    for i in objList:
        print(i)   # Iterates through the list showing all of the objects added
    for i in objList:
        if Obj(i):
            print(i, 'has already been created.')   # Checks for existance of object, if so skips creation
        else:
            createObj = Obj(i)   # Creates object if it doesn't exist
    choice = input('Add object? (y / n): ')
    if choice == 'y':
        newObject = input('Name of object to add: ')
        if newObject in objList:   # Checks for existance of user enrty in list
            print(newObject, 'already exists.')   # Skips .append if item already in list
        else:
            objList.append(newObject)   # Adds entry if not already in list

print('Goodbye!')
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Add object? (y / n): y
Name of object to add: apple
apple
You have created a new object: apple   # At this point, everything is correct
apple has already been created.   # Why is it giving me both conditions for my "if" statement?
Add object? (y / n): y
Name of object to add: pear
apple
pear
You have created a new object: apple   # Was not intending to re-create this object
apple has already been created.
You have created a new object: pear   # Only this one should be created at this point
pear has already been created.   # Huh???
Add object? (y / n): n
Goodbye!
```

I've already done some research and read several comments about creating a dict to do what it appears I'm trying to do. I've already built a program that does this using a dict, but for learning purposes, I'm trying to understand if this can be done by creating objects instead. It appears as though everything works, except for when the program checks for the existance of an object by iterating through the list, then it fails.

I then did this:

```
>>> Obj('dog')
You have created a new object: dog
<__main__.Obj object at 0x02F54B50>
>>> if Obj('dog'):
    print('exists')

You have created a new object: dog
exists
```

This leads me to a theory. When I put in the "if" statement, is it creating a new instance of an object named, "dog" ? And if so, how can I check for the existance of an object? If I store the object in a variable, won't the loop from my top snippet over-write the variable with each iteration? And is my "print" statement running because the object exists, or because its the next line of code? Sorry for the length of my question, but I'm sure I can get a better answer if I provide better information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are just containers for data and functions. Even though `Obj("dog")` and `Obj("dog")` are equivalent, they are not identical. In other words, every time you call `__init__` you are getting a completely new *copy*. All objects that are not `None`, `0` or `False` evaluate to `True` and so your `if` statement succeeds.

You still must use a dictionary to see if you've created a dog in the past. For instance,

```
objects = { "dog" : Obj("dog"), "cat" : Obj("cat") }
if "cat" in objects:
    print objects["cat"].x  # prints cat
```

Comment: That is helpful. So even if I create a new Obj('dog'), the new one is different from the one already created and my loop will continue to add more instances of Obj('dog') as long as I type it in? I assume this is because each instance is stored in a different spot in the memory, i.e. <__main__.Obj object at 0x02F54B50> ?

Comment: And for the second part, the dictionary should be used in conjunction with the objects and lists? Makes sense after reading you explanantion. But then I must ask this self-defeating question, why bother using objects in this scenario?

Comment: I wouldn't in this scenario. Objects should encapsulate multiple, related pieces of information and the functionality that goes with it. Objects are such a large topic it would be hard to explain when to use them here.